# search string in textfile

Tags: c++, c, string, text

Say you have a text file like this

all you want from the text is the "**size value**"

but repeats more that thousand time with different value

```
"field_pic_flag : 0 
bottom_field_flag : 0 
idr_pic_id : 0 
Found NAL at offset  ,size 28813  !! Found NAL"

"field_pic_flag : 0 
bottom_field_flag : 0 
idr_pic_id : 0 
Found NAL at offset  ,size 210  !! Found NAL"
```

**Results**
i just want a code to write a text file with this format as shown below

`size 28813 
 size 210
 and so on`

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use C/C++ for that ? Some kind of `grep` / `awk` / `perl` script looks better suited to the job...

Comment: Cause, really, `grep "size [0-9]*" -o yourfile.txt > result.txt` ...

Comment: thanks for you quick reply i just need the first 50 of the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using C/C++ is not mandatory, then `grep` is probably your friend :

```
grep "size [0-9]*" -o yourfile.txt > all_sizes.txt
```

And if you only need the 50 first results, `head` it is :

```
head -n 50 all_sizes > result.txt
```

(Now, this assumes you're using some kind of Unix, or OS X ...)

Comment: say the values in file should be multiplied by 8 just to convert bytes to bite. how to do it

Comment: Then that's a different question. In all cases, you're going to do string manipulation, so any scripting language (python, ruby, etc...) would be more suited to the task than C/C++. Unless it's for homeworks, in which case you should tag your question accordingly ;)...

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the question is tagged as C/C++. If you're allowed to use C++ 11, than you can easily use the new introduced regex library.

In the code bellow the data is stored directly in a string, but you can easily read it from a file. The results is saved in the result.txt file, been displayed on the screen at the same time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex> // The new library introduced in C++ 11
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    const int n = 50;
    int i = 0;

    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("result.txt");

    // You can read this string from your input file
    std::string s("\"field_pic_flag : 0\
        bottom_field_flag : 0\
        idr_pic_id : 0\
        Found NAL at offset, size 28813  !!Found NAL\"\
        \"field_pic_flag : 0\
        bottom_field_flag : 0\
        idr_pic_id : 0\
        Found NAL at offset, size 210  !!Found NAL\"");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex e("size [0-9]*");   

    while (std::regex_search(s, m, e) && i++<n) {
        for (auto x : m) {
            std::cout << x << " ";
            outputFile << x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        outputFile << std::endl;
        s = m.suffix().str();
    }

    outputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

A classical solution will require a little more effort.